# Error while getting current location in Here SDK on Flutter

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps

When I calculate the route and start, I get an error like in the video below.

- How can I solve this situation?
- How can I handle this situation in try-catch?

[Here is the screen record](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWV4Vren0Ao)

Also, there is no error in my console. All I see is the log "Are you off-road?" And the app crashes after a while.

Here version: 4.8.0.0

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I assume you are using the VisualNavigator to render this. In that case you are able to control and log the locations you set. For your video, it may be worth to check if the bearing value is causing the rotation. From your question it is not clear if you get this error repeatedly or just randomly. Either way, I would recommend to try a newer HERE SDK version >= 4.9.0.